# Poliigon.com leaf textures

Tags: texturing

I'm new here and I started working on making an ultra realistic tree.

I made a nice bone on which I should continue working, but when I previously made something like this the leaf texture was cut in two parts"

- front leaf
- back leaf

For some reason when I got the texture from Poliigon.com, the back and the front are merged together. I'm 90% sure there s some trick to that which will make my work so much easier, but I can t see it.

Here s a pic of how the texture looks like:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ezth42nmoxs7bq/floare..png?dl=0

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Link gives a 404 error

Comment: Please use the tools on this site to make the images part of the question. Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Comment: I m sorry, I don t know how I messed the link. It s good now

Comment: Either split the texture into two using Photoshop, Gimp, etc. so you have what you are used to or use UV mapping to map different parts of the leaf to different parts on the texture. Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/introduction.html

Comment: What about the normal, glossy,ref map?

Comment: My first approach would be to duplicate the UV map, shift the second one and use that as texture coordinate input for the backface textures.

Comment: Can you please add a translation to that? 0.0
I started making some pretty sick node maps, but I m still not familiar with everything.
If you could please make an example in blender of what you have just said it would be perfect, thanks!

Comment: Reynante Martinez just released an article about this: http://www.reynantemartinez.com/double-sided-texturing-in-cycles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mirror UV

Once you unwrapped the geoemetry, I would duplicate the uvmap with the "+" button on the right and then flip the UV islands on the other side of the texture. This way you just have to pick the right coordinate (in cyles for example the UV node as shown below) for two istances of the same texture and mix them with backfacing factor.

[image]

Reynante Martinez wrote an article about Double-Sided Texturing in Cycles, you can read it at: http://www.reynantemartinez.com/double-sided-texturing-in-cycles.html.

---

You can also take advantage of the Vector Mapping node to automatically flip your UV so you'll even not need to duplicate your UV map. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it clarified me on how to do the texture, but what about the gloss and the normal map for the leaf? 
I m sorry if I m asking too much, but it s one of the few times when I just couldn t find something on the internet

Comment: Could you clarify what aspect is not clear? How to mix all the maps to create a shader with diffuse/spec/bump (and in this case I would point you to any of the tutorial where a shader is built, for example: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/photorealistic-wood/..) or something else?

Comment: Can we talk via some instant text app or site? I think that should be better.
Discord: stefanstgs#1535
Skype:cacaracterul

Comment: Sorry, but I'm quite busy this days. I suggest to write down your doubt in a chat room (here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58733/poliigon-com-leaf-textures) and I'll be glad to read and answer when I can

Comment: Well, first of all, i tried ur method and it seems like the leafs have been rotated? or shrieked?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2jp6jvvsy8dfsl/floare%20nu%20mere.png?dl=0 (A pic of how it looks for me)
I did the same node map as urs with the transparent node.

Comment: Well, one way or another, I made it work! I have just finished the dang leaf and I thought I should share the finished produc!
Thank you realling much for all your help, you guys are lovely. My leaf is now complete and ready to be put on a tree :D
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7czma977j2v1xpm/floare%20nu%20mere15.png?dl=0